# Unknown issuer on tls handshake in Rust with async-tls

Tags: ssl, rust, backend

I was building my client-server application with [async-tls](https://github.com/async-rs/async-tls) doing something really similar to the [examples](https://github.com/async-rs/async-tls/tree/master/examples) but when I try to perform the TLS handshake it panics with this error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Awaiting TLS failed: Custom { kind: InvalidData, error: WebPKIError(UnknownIssuer) }', src/main.rs:15:26
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

My code in the client is simply:

```rust
let tcp_stream = TcpStream::connect("localhost:5568")
    .await
    .expect("TCP handshake failed.");

let tls_connector = TlsConnector::default();
let mut tls_stream = tls_connector
    .connect("localhost", tcp_stream)
    .expect("TLS handshake failed.")
    .await
    .expect("Awaiting TLS failed");
```

Also I've copied the CA certificate under `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` and ran 
`sudo update-ca-certificates`
 (linux of course).
Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using [rustls](https://github.com/ctz/rustls) which doesn't integrate OS certificates.

Solved with this:

```rust
let mut config = ClientConfig::new();

let cafile = Path::new("path of trusted CA chain");
let file = async_std::fs::read(cafile)
    .await
    .expect("Failed to read file.");
let mut pem = Cursor::new(file);
config
    .root_store
    .add_pem_file(&mut pem)
    .map_err(|_| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::InvalidInput, "invalid cert"))
    .expect("Unable to create configuration object.");

let tls_connector = TlsConnector::from(Arc::new(config));
```

Thanks u/Wilem82 (from reddit) for the hint.

Comment: And thank you for (1) cross-posting the answer and (2) fleshing it out into a full code sample :)

Comment: I am not sure which version you use, but since 0.9.2 you can use `RustlsConnector::new_with_native_certs()`, see https://docs.rs/rustls-connector/0.13.1/rustls_connector/struct.RustlsConnector.html#method.new_with_native_certs